# Intellij IDEA breakpoints; how to backtrack into a method

Tags: android

when debugging, if you click to step over a method is the only way to step into it to rerun and do so or is there a backtrack option to see what occurred (not backtrack and run from that point cause it's obviously passed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can highlight the section and it will show variables in the debug section. If not, check options in program structure or settings area to enable but it was default on mine.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping it would break it down more in threads section but I guess that's because it's skipped. Otherwise, the variables section definitely shows a lot of what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: can you post code for the break points? I might be able to help from there. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I just learned that the thread I'm using runs a portion in the background rather than one piece after another so the timing is off in my app when changing pictures. I'm trying to learn to debug and figure out what  else I could try instead to insure things start when I want it to.

Comment: Have you tried AsyncTask? similar to threads but easier to manipulate. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: no I haven't. I'll have to read up on it and give it a shot!  Thanks again for your help.